# Are Ethernet magnetics temperature sensitive

Tags: temperature, ethernet, signal-integrity

I am using these discrete Ethernet transformers [ALT4532M-201-T001](https://product.tdk.com/system/files/dam/doc/product/transformer/transformer/lan/catalog/trans_alt_en.pdf). According to the datasheet, they are rated for -40ºC to +85ºC.

[image: Discrete Ethernet magnetics]

In general for Ethernet transformers, would I expect to see some degradation in performance as the temperature approaches 85ºC? Or should they behave the same across their temperature range?

Comment: I would expect performance degradation in any magnetics that get too close to the Curie point, but I doubt 85 °C is the Curie point of the ferrite--more likely it's a limit imposed by the magnet wire, plastic clips, or some other part of the transformer.

Comment: They will **not** behave the same over temperature (almost nothing does) but they don't need to as long as their behavior is "good enough" over temperature. The datasheet you linked does not say anything about behavior over temperature so we can only guess.

Answer (score 4):

Here is the temperature behavior of a TDK [ferrite](https://www.dextermag.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/TDK_Dexter_Ferrites_Telecommunication_Materials_LAN_Pulse_Transformers.pdf) material used in 100base-T transformers, and comparison with other typical materials.

[image]

As you can see there's not a lot of effect on the intial permeability, but the incremental permeability suffers a significant drop at higher temperatures, especially the HP5 material.

If you enquire of the transformer manufacturer (TDK), perhaps they will share the material characteristics or at least the ferrite material name. Since TDK is a major supplier of ferrites they should not have a problem with that- it's probably a product made by TDK themselves.

Beyond the ferrite response there are also the temperature limitations of the wire insulation and perhaps adhesives and other materials used in the construction. Probably you're not close to their long-term limits though, given that they can withstand a short-term run through a reflow oven.

Answer (score 1):

The component seems to be rated for standard industrial range from -40 to +85 degrees C.

Which basically means that the components are guaranteed to fully operate for its intended purpose within this range up to 85 C.

There is a good chance that it works without problems outside of this range, say at 86 degrees C at least for a short period, but if it happens to break immediately or degrades so that it only works only for 1 year instead of 10 years, the manufacturer is not liable since you used the part outside of range.

Answer (score 0):

All magnetics reduce in permeability with rising temperature and transformers must have a high Q factor at 100 MHz at room temp to support the temperature range and degradation expected in Q at max temp. And max frequency of the spectrum which is not flat either.

Since Q=XL(f)/R you would expect that XL is much higher than 50 Ohms in order for the terminations to determine the transmission line impedance.  You should expect your distributor to get you the temperature curves from TDK if you are an important customer. Otherwise you ought to test  the magnetics properties with an RLC meter over temperature as these determine the performance along with your design and layout in a circuit Extended cable Margin measured eye-pattern Test.

Comment: *"All magnetics reduce in permeability with rising temperature"* No. Quite the opposite in fact. Magnetic anisotropy drops faster with temperature than magnetic moment for wide ranges of temperatures and material. this makes materials easier to magnetize, thus permeability *higher*. but they will also saturate much sooner and at lower B.

Comment: TY @tobalt I guess my experience with magnetic disk drives was unique. So why does μ∆ vs. TEMP have a negative slope above 20'C with DC bias, albeit Phy may only be < 10mA

Comment: I suppose these are very soft magnetic ferrites which were optimized to have their maximum permeability at intended operation temperature. The bias brings them closer to saturation, so if (due to higher temperature) the B-H curve is already so steep that one approaches the saturation, the permability would drop over T although at zero bias it would in fact be higher. In PMR it is the same trend with T btw: basically *no* permeability to small fields at regular temps, but when getting too hot the anisotropy collapses and permebility increases.

Comment: yes the higher coercivity medium is inherently thermally more stable